# Question on Fourier Transform

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, fourier-analysis

Fourier transform on $f$:
$$\hat{f}(\xi)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x)e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}dx$$
$\xi\in\mathbb{R}^d$.

How to show that 
$$\hat{f}(\xi)=\frac{1}{2}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}[f(x)-f(x-\xi')]e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}dx$$
where $\xi'=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\xi}{|\xi|^2}$.

By translation-invariance of integration, I get
\begin{eqnarray*}
\hat{f}(\xi)&=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x-\xi')e^{-2\pi i(x-\xi')\cdot\xi}dx\\
&=&\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}f(x-\xi')e^{-2\pi ix\cdot\xi}e^{2\pi i\xi'\xi}dx\\
\end{eqnarray*}
What to do next? Does $e^{2\pi i\xi'\xi}=-1$? I am not very familiar with complex number.

Comment: Look at the definition of $\xi'$. You have $\xi'\cdot \xi = \frac12$, so the factor is $e^{2\pi i\frac12} = e^{\pi i} = -1$.